# custom Js error in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Configuration')]")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);

//Click on Assets link
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Assets')]")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
//Click on Assets Makes link
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Asset Makes')]")).click();

Thread.sleep(7000);


String divMsg = driver.findElement(By.id("btn_add_appliance_makes")).getText();
System.out.println(divMsg);

driver.findElement(By.id("btn_add_appliance_makes")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

> js/custom_js.js, line 904: TypeError: $(...).validate(...) is undefined

How do I solve this issue in selenium web driver? When I click on last code button, I found error. I don't know if it's because of my code or it's from the developer end.

Comment: How are you sure that `When I click on last code button, I found error` ? Can you provide the full error stacktrace & the relevant HTML DOM? Thanks

Comment: I debug my code and found that on that particular click i got error .

Comment: Great !!! It seems you have got an Answer Accepted :) assuming your Question got Answered let the Question RIP. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using any JavaScript with jquery in your code then the problem with dev code only.